# save or update for a model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following structure:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(B, unique=True)
    b = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.b += 1
        super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I wanted to increment "b" by 1 whenever its saved. This works fine when I add the item the first time otherwise it fails because of the "uniqueTrue" clause.

How do I let Django "update if exists" otherwise "create new". The model does just increments the count.

Thanks.

Comment: That is the normal behaviour of Django. Your problem is elsewhere. Please show the view that calls this code.

Comment: I am handling directly from Admin no view. The uniqueTrue on "a" is giving the problem, when I try to "add" a new value. It doesn't update in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The creation happens when you get an object. If you have a problem with saving duplicates, that is probably where you should be looking.

```
A.objects.get_or_create()
```

should get an object if it exists, create otherwise. You can examine it's pk to see if it *is* the same object, or a duplicate. Refer [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Comment: In the admin, I simply "add A" and if the item exists I want to update or add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if "self.id" existe. If it is True, then you are updating, else you are creating a new record.